# How to use an IF statement in a WHILE function

Tags: php

I have the following pagination:

```
<ul class="pagination">
  <li><a href="<?php if ($page_no > 1 ){echo $page_no - 1;} else{echo '#';} ?>">&laquo;</a></li>

    <?php 
    $i = 1;
    while ($i<=$pages):
    echo '<li><a href="'. URL . 'reviews?page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a></li>';
    $i++;
    endwhile;
    ?>

  <li><a href="<?php if ($page_no <= $pages){echo $page_no + 1;} ?>">&raquo;</a></li>
</ul>
```

This works fine. I now want to add `class="active"` to the relevant `<li>`. I would have thought this would work:

```
$i = 1;
while ($i<=$pages):
  $a = $i;
  echo '<li ';
  if ($a = $_GET['page']){echo 'class="active"';};
  echo '><a href="'. URL . 'reviews?page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a></li>';
$i++;
endwhile;
```

Where `$_GET[page]` is the relevant page number in the pagination. However, this returns ALL `<li>` as active. What have I missed?

Comment: `$a == $_GET['page']` I must resist temptation to post it as a full answer. ))

Comment: You cannot assign in an IF STATEMENT

Comment: "=" is different from "==". The first one is an assignment operator whereas second one  is a comparison operator.

Comment: @raina77ow how about a sentence? :)

Comment: @alias51 Now, seriously, one time I did the similar thing I almost got myself some nice shiny Peer Pressure badge. ) Not without a reason, have to say. ))

Comment: I dislike seeing if statements in the middle of tags. IDR PHP but I think if $a==... { echo '<li class="active">' is more neat. I would do it in a way where I could write `<li $Active><a href="$url">...` but idk if you can do that in php.

Comment: I just checked. PHP CAN do what I suggested to my surpise. `<?php $yourface="Test"; echo "I see $yourface"; ?>` <-- This works. Just remember to use htmlspecialchars when you using user/database/external data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a second `=` to `$a = $_GET['page']` so that it's like this:

```
$i = 1;
while ($i<=$pages):
  $a = $i;
  echo '<li ';
  if ($a == $_GET['page']){echo 'class="active"';}
  echo '><a href="'. URL . 'reviews?page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a></li>';
$i++;
endwhile;
```

Also remove the `;` after the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

This would give your desired result

```
$i = 1;
while ($i<=$pages):
  $a = $i;
  echo '<li ' . $a == $_GET['page'] ? 'class="active"': '';
  echo '><a href="'. URL . 'reviews?page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a></li>';
$i++;
endwhile;
```